# Germany: Lost job on D visa

Tags: germany, working-visas, immigration, blue-card

I am a non EU national and found the job in Germany. I started working remotely on freelancer contract meanwhile I got the blue card visa as well. I couldn't find an apartment in Germany and due to timezone issues my work performance was also impacted so company decided to part ways.

I found a new job and my national D visa is valid for 2.5 more months so I'm wondering can I enter the germany with current visa which has the past employer name printed on it and go to the local authorities with new job offer?

Im avoiding applying for new visa at the embassy in my country due to long waiting times of up to 4-5 months.